# Finding a condition on models that validate theorems

Tags: modal-logic

I want to find a condition on standard models for which $\Diamond A \rightarrow \Box A$ is a theorem.  I can see that the condition

> $\forall w_1,w_2,w_3\in W$ if $w_1Rw_2$ and $w_1Rw_3$ then $w_2=w_3$

would be a sufficient condition but it seems to me it wouldn't be a necessary condition.  Does anyone know a necessary and sufficient condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mauro Allegranza's answer shows that your condition is not only sufficient but also necessary, but the actual proof is left as an exercise.  Here's a solution to that exercise.  I'll prove the contrapositive; I assume your condition is not satisfied, so some $w_1$ is $R$-related to two distinct elements $w_2$ and $w_3$, and I'll show that that $\Diamond A\to\Box A$ isn't valid in such a model.  Interpret $A$ as being true at $w_2$ and false at $w_3$.  (It doesn't matter how $A$ is interpreted anywhere else.)  Then $\Diamond A$ is true at $w_1$ (because $A$ is true at $w_2$) but $\Box A$ is false at $w_1$ (because $A$ is false at $w_3$), so the implication $\Diamond A\to\Box A$ is false at $w_1$.

Comment: Nicely said, I was thinking it wasn't sufficient because I could think of a world where the condition doesn't hold yet the formula was true--but of course you're right, I need to think of a model where the condition holds everywhere and yet the formula not true at some world for some sentence, which as you showed is impossible..

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the condition you have stated is an **iff** condition.

See :

- Brian Chellas,  [Modal Logic : An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=YupiXWV5j6cC&pg=PA88) (1980), page 85-on for the $G^{k,l,m,n}$ schema :

> $$\Diamond^k \Box^l A \to \Box^m \Diamond^l A.$$

Thus, your formula is the case with $1,0,1,0$.

Then, see **EXERCISE 3.38** [page 90] :

> Prove that $1,0,1,0$-incestuality is the same as :
>
> > *partial functionality* : if $\alpha R \beta$ and $\alpha R \gamma$, then $\beta=\gamma$

where [page 88] we say that :

> $R$ is $k, l, m, n$-*incestual* if and only if for every $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathcal M$,
>
> > if $\alpha R^k \beta$ and $\alpha R^m \gamma$, then for some $\delta \in \mathcal M$, $\beta R^l \delta$ and $\gamma R^ n \delta$.
>
> **Theorem3.8**. *The schema* $G^{k,l,m,n}$ *is valid in the class of* $k, l, m, n$-*incestual* *standard models*.